# why data binding doesn't work for my custom attribute directive

Tags: javascript, angular

Below is my code, I omit component code for abbreviation:

**template.html**

```
 ...
 <tr *ngFor="let item of getProducts(); let i = index"
     [pa-attr]="getProducts().length < 6 ? 'bg-success' : 'bg-warning'">
     <td>{{item.name}}</td>             
 </tr>
```

and below is the custom attribute directive code:

```
@Directive({
    selector: "[pa-attr]",
})
export class PaAttrDirective {

    constructor(private element: ElementRef) {
        console.log('been called')
    }

    @Input("pa-attr")
    bgClass: string;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.element.nativeElement.classList.add(this.bgClass || "bg-success",
            "text-white");
    }
}
```

Currently I have 5 items as:
[image]

then I add a new item, then I have:
[image]

I'm confused here,why only the sixth item's color is changed to yellow(bg-warning)? should it be that all items' color should be changed to yellow? Because when I added a new item, the data source of `getProducts()` changes, so `getProducts().length` returns six items, since the data source changes, the whole `<tr>` should be  reevaluated, so now each item's from 1th to sixth should be in yellow, isn't it? so why only the sixth item is in yellow?

Comment: Can't you just use [ngClass] instead of your own [pa-attr]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"since the data source changes, the whole <tr> should be reevaluated"` - this statement is incorrect.

`*ngFor` has a number of optimizations under the hood. In this scenario the first 5 `<tr>` instances remain unchanged and only a single new instance is added.

> When the contents of the iterator changes, `NgForOf` makes the
>   corresponding changes to the DOM:
>
> - When an item is added, a new instance of the template is added to the DOM.
> - When an item is removed, its template instance is removed from the DOM.
> - When items are reordered, their respective templates are reordered in the DOM.
>
> Angular uses object identity to track insertions and deletions within
>   the iterator and reproduce those changes in the DOM.

If you take a look at the console when adding the 6th product you will only see a single additional 'been called' message.

As the value of `this.bgClass` is only read during the `ngOnInit` hook of your directive, only new `<tr>` instances will appear yellow.

Comment: OK, I get your point, so the first 5 items remains in the dom, they are not re-created as I originally thought. So if do want all the item in yellow as long as the total item number is >= 6, how can I turn off ngFor optimizations?

Comment: You can do this without a custom directive. `ngClass` does what you need. `<tr [ngClass]="getProducts().length < 6 ? 'bg-success' : 'bg-warning'"`

Answer (score 0):

I don't do a whole lot of Angular, but this looks like I'd expect from the code presented. Each time it runs through the loop (`let item of getProducts()`), the first 5 `<tr>` (table *rows*) are going to have the `bg-success` class applied because of the logic in the `[pa-attr]` attribute, with everything beyond having `bg-warning` applied.